# How to break line in web page?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I want to format the content before showing to web page. I am storing '\r\n\' as enter in Database and trying to replace it before show content on the web page. server side my code is:

```
lblComments.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem).Row["Comment"].ToString().Replace("\r\n", "<br>"));
```

I have use `Server.HtmlEncode`.

My Out put should be:

```
Comment Type: Public
Comment: Commented on the Data by user A
```

But, its shows me everything in single line.

Comment: What is the actual output? When you view source of the rendered page, do you see the `<br>` elements or do you get the `\r\n`?

Comment: Be careful of `\r\n`, that's the line terminator on Windows only, are you sure you'll never have to deal with unix/mac formatted files?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
.Replace("\r\n", "<br/>")
```

And only **AFTER** Server.HtmlEncode, because you don't want the `<br/>` itself to get encoded to `&lt;br/&gt;` (raw), displaying as `<br/>` literally.

Comment: If the `<br>` were HTML encoded, I would expect to see `<br>` rendered on the page. That's not what the OP has posted.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the output in a `<pre>...</pre>` element instead of replacing the line breaks with `<br>`. That way, the line breaks should be conserved.

E.g. put a `<pre>` element around your Label:

```
<pre><asp:Label id="lblComments" runat="server" /></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Replace("\n", "<br>")
```

This test worked without encode

```
string comments = @"Comment Type: Public
Comment: Commented on the Data by user A";
lblComments.Text = comments.Replace("\n","<br>");
```